# Ошибка в консоли при запуске gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm, browsersync, gulp-watch

При запуске gulp watch появляется ошибка

> [error] You tried to start Browsersync twice! To create multiple
>   instances, use browserSync.create().init()

gulp watch обновляет страницу, но через раз

**gulpfile**:

```
var gulp          = require('gulp'),
    sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
    concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
    clean         = require('gulp-clean'),
    rename        = require('gulp-rename'),
    pug           = require('gulp-pug'),
    copy          = require('gulp-copy'),
    browserSync   = require('browser-sync'),
    autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    imagemin      = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src(['app/scss/*.scss','!app/scss/includeFonts.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], {cascade: true}))
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/style/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src ('app/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({pretty:true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('fonts', function(){
    gulp.src('app/scss/includeFonts.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(concat('fonts.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/style/'))
});





gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(['dist/scripts/libs.js', 'dist/style/libs.css'], {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('buildConfigJs', function(){
    return gulp.src(['bower_components/*/dist/**/*.min.js','!bower_components/*/dist/**/*.slim.min.js'])
    .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts/'));
});

gulp.task('buildConfigCss', function(){
    return gulp.src('bower_components/*/dist/**/*.min.css')
    .pipe(concat('libs.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/style/'));
});

gulp.task('buildConfig', ['buildConfigCss','buildConfigJs'])




// gulp.task('buildCss', function(){
//  return gulp.src('app/css/*.css')
//  .pipe(concat('style.css'))
//  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/style/'))
// });

gulp.task('buildJs', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('imgCopy',function(){
    return gulp.src('app/images/*.*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
});

gulp.task('fontsCopy',function(){
    return gulp.src('app/fonts/*.*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
});

gulp.task('build', ['sass','buildJs','imgCopy','pug','fontsCopy']);



gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
    browserSync({
        server :{
            baseDir: 'dist'
        },
        browser: 'chrome'
    });
});






gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass', 'pug', 'buildJs','fonts'], function () {
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.scss', [sass]);
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.pug', [pug]);
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.js', ['buildJs']);
});
```

**package.js**

```
{
  "name": "kdd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Andrey Denisov",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.5",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-copy": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-pug": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bower-canary": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-jquery": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В топку Gulp - юзай webpack
2. Если говорит, что уже запущен инстанс, то попробуй найти этот процесс и вырубить его. Можешь просто снести все node.exe процессы и перезапустить.
   Каков результат?

Comment: Пока необходимо юзать gulp. Оффнуть процессы - не помогло